# How to get TOC and Widgets (scalebar, overviewmap and basemapgallery) all working with ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Yesterday I spent many hours trying to get a scalebar, overviewmap and basemapgallery working in one webmap using nilu'S **[TOC](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109)**.

Unfortunately without success :(

I have one version, where scalebar and overviewmap work (but not the basemapgallery) and another version, where scalebar and basemapgallery work (but not the overviewmap).

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crqge/)** of the version with working scalebar and basemapgallery work (but not the overviewmap):

As you can see in the fiddle the OverviewMap Widget is already included.

I have absolutely no idea what I have missed in the code. However, I think something must be misplaced.

Can anyone suggest what may be astray?

Comment: Which JSAPI version you wants to use? (According to JS Fiddle its 3.5)

Comment: Jepp...it's 3.5. Widgets (Scalebar, Overviewmap, Basemapgallery) should all work with 3.5. Of course I would be willing to switch to another version 3.6 or even 3.7), but because of limited skill I was not able to switch to another version -.- The main thing is that it works.